# swift on visual studio code using windows

Tags: swift, xcode, windows, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code to code swift on my windows pc i installed the latest swift version which is [swift 5.3](https://swift.org/download/#releases)
after that i downloaded the extension of swift on visual studio code called Swift language and i downloaded code runner, i made a .swift file and started coding on it when i press on run code
this is the error that show up

*C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows.platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/SwiftStdint.h:28:10: error: 'stdint.h' file not found
#include <stdint.h>
^
:0: error: could not build C module 'SwiftShims'*

Comment: seems like there are missing some files

Answer (score 0):

try putting these commands in the terminal, it should work.

```
set SDKROOT=%SystemDrive%/Library/Developer/Platforms/Windows.platform/Developer/SDKs/Windows.sdk

set SWIFTFLAGS=-sdk %SDKROOT% -I %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift -L %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift/windows

swiftc -o example.exe example.swift %SWIFTFLAGS%
```

Note - For the last command replace example before .swift and .exe with the name of your file.